# How can i copy from Session Data without reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, clone

I have `Session object` and how can i copy this value without reference.

```
var temp=new T(Session["Tdata"] as T);

temp.DataCount.RemoveAt(1);
```

My T class is

```
public T()
{
 DataCount=new List<int>();
}

public T(T tempt)
{
    DataCount=tempt.DataCount;
}

public List<int> DataCount{get;set;}
```

When i remove `DataCount` from temp.Its also remove from `Session["Tdata"]`.I dont want to remove it from Session.Google say it cause because `reference type`  .Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<int>` is a reference type, just like `T` is. So when your copy constructor copies the original's `DataCount` property, it's not copying the sequence of values, it's copying the original `List<int>` itself - so naturally, changes to one are reflected in the other.

Change your copy constructor to create a *new* list, but with the same original members. Luckily, `List<int>`'s constructor accepts an existing list and takes its members:

```
public T(T tempt)
{
    DataCount = new List<int>(tempt.DataCount);
}
```